# R Code | Send Outlook email in R, looping multiple email addresses, html table in body of email

Tags: r, loops, outlook

I would like a code to read dataframe (df). Thereafter, send email in Microsoft Outlook, by looping through Email list, create a subset of the list by distinct Email, then email this list in HTML table format to email recipient.

df =

```
structure(list(Sponsor.Name = c("X", "Z", "MP"), Team.Name = c("Y", 
"P", "HK"), Email = c("x@gmail.com", "y@gmail.com", "x@gmail.com"
), Amount = c(10, 20, 100)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

For example; "x@gmail.com", will have a HTML output table of two entries.

I have found the following useful:

1. [How to show an excel worksheet in outlook body by R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41282094/how-to-show-an-excel-worksheet-in-outlook-body-by-r)
2. [For loop on data frame with multiple columns to send mails in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607626/for-loop-on-data-frame-with-multiple-columns-to-send-mails-in-r)

but I am unable to replicate it for my use.

Look forward to your assistance.

```
     library(RDCOMClient)
     library(openxlsx)
     library(xtable)
     library(dplyr)

     OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
     outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
     outMail[["To"]] = "test@gmail.com" #insert real email address here
     outMail[["subject"]] = paste0("Report ", Sys.Date() - 1)


    df<-read.xlsx("email_test.xlsx")
     

    emails<-df %>% distinct(df$Email) #read df file
    split_emails<-split(df, emails)
    iwalk(split_emails, ~print(xtable(df), type="html", print.results=FALSE)) #doesnot work
```

Thank you

Comment: [This](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Microsoft365R/vignettes/outlook.html) might help.

Comment: Thank you. However, how do I loop through email addresses in df and then embed table filtered by email into body of email?